# how to set parameters in ndt_mapping while my velodyne is slant to create 3D Map

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to generate 3D point cloud map in my campus,and my velodyne_16 is fixed to the car at a certain Angle,how can I set the parameters in ndt_mapping to genrate a better map.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359205/how-to-set-parameters-in-ndt_mapping-while-my-velodyne-is-slant-to-create-3d-map/) by [NJUST](https://answers.ros.org/users/57405/njust/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am assuming you mean the transfrom between the velodyne and the base_link (vehicle coordinates). You can use the GUI (roslaunch runtime_manager runtime_manager.launch) to set the ros parameters that NDT mappings uses for the transform between the sensor and base_link.[image: autoware gui, transform is highlighted in orange].

or you can just set the [rosparams](http://wiki.ros.org/rosparam) in a terminal using "rosparam set param_name value".
The parameter names are: tf_x ,tf_y, tf_z, tf_yaw, tf_pitch, tf_roll. These could be set in a launch file also.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick N.](https://answers.ros.org/users/47634/patrick-n./) with karma: 65 on 2020-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1